# как отправить фотографию с бэкенда на фронтенд nodejs express

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, buffer

Всем привет,я хочу отправить фото с бэкенда на фронтенд и установить его по умолчанию в `<input type="file">` и как я понял мне надо отправить буффер с бэкенда на фронт енд.Вот мой контролер в бэкенде отвечающий за это

```
  async getRecipePhoto(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const fileName = req.params.name;
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../static", `${fileName}`);
      const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
      console.log(fileData);
      res.json(fileData);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

и на фронтенде мне нужно превратить его в blob и потом конечно в file

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
console.log(dataPhotoOfRecipe);
if (isSuccessPhotoOfRecipe) {
  const photoBlob = new Blob([dataPhotoOfRecipe?.data], {
    type: "image/jpeg",
  });

  const file = new File([photoBlob], dataRecipe?.img, {
    type: "image/jpeg",
  });

  console.log(file);

  // setPhoto(photoFile);
  // console.log(photoFile);
}
```

}, [isSuccessPhotoOfRecipe]);
`
вот мой запрос

```
  const {
    data: dataPhotoOfRecipe,
    isLoading: isLoadingPhotoOfRecipe,
    isSuccess: isSuccessPhotoOfRecipe,
  } = useGetRecipePhotoQuery(dataRecipe?.img, {
    skip: !isSuccessRecipe === true,
  });
```

Вот настройки запроса

getRecipePhoto: builder.query({
query: (body) => ({
url: `/recipeOfPhoto/${body}`,
}),
}),

Но у меня почему то в объекте файла отстуствует поле data с буффером,но есть размер[image: вот фотография],что мне делать?

Comment: Куда? Кому? Зачем? При каком событии? + дополните вопрос кодом, что за буфер у вас и как вы его получаете

Comment: Понял,cпасибо,я дополнил.Буду очень благодарен если вы поможете

Comment: Не нужно этого делать. Отправлять файл с сервера что бы потом опять передать его на сервер это извращение какое-то.

Comment: Я сейчас пишу редактирование рецепта) И хочу чтобы пользователь мог менять фотографию и соответсвенно мне надо чтобы в инпуте показовалась выбранная им раньше фотка)

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Фотка должна показываться где-то рядом, но  нет никакого смысла извращаться и пытаться запихать её именно в input.

Answer (score 1):

Для возврата файла из метода API можно использовать метод `res.download`

```js
  async getRecipePhoto(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const fileName = req.params.name;
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../static", fileName);
      res.download(filePath);
    } catch (e) {
        // возможно, исключение-таки стоит обработать, вернув статус 500, например
    }
  }
```

Comment: Да,я получаю фотографию в предварительном ответе,но когда логирую результат запроса то получаю undefined,похожий результат был когда я использовал res.sendFile(filePath),но мне надо чтобы был объект файла

Comment: а как именно делаете запрос на фронтенде? в вопросе нет кода получения `dataPhotoOfRecipe`

Comment: А,извиняюсь,сейчас дополню,но если вкратце то через RTK query

Comment: Я дополнили,буду очень рад если вы мне поможете!

Comment: вот тут можно найти пример скачивания файла через RTK query:  
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1522

можно попробовать изменить запрос следующим образом:  


getRecipePhoto: builder.query({ query: (body) => ({  
    url: /recipeOfPhoto/${body},  
    /* добавить responseHandler и cache */  
    responseHandler: ((response) => response.blob()),  
    cache: "no-cache"  
}), })

Comment: Благодарю,сейчас побегу смотреть!)

Comment: A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `RecipeApi.queries.getRecipePhoto("5c749ddc-a331-43db-9a1c-a51aac5c061c.jpg").data`. Value: Blob {size: 25512, type: 'image/jpeg'}  выдает такую ошибку:(